# writing a gene vector table from two characters

Tags: r, vector, character

I have two data frames with sequencing data in them. One large 'background' set of counts called genes.txt, and one smaller set of differentially expressed genes called degenes.txt. Each data frame has several columns, including one called 'symbol' that contains the gene symbol in the form 'Car9' for example. I need to take the columns of gene symbols from each and make a new table with all of the background gene symbols, and a 0 or 1 for differentially expressed or not.

```
newcounts <- read.table("genes.txt", header=T,sep="\t",check.names=F, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(newcounts)

# create a list of the 45000 background genes
backgroundgenes <- as.character(newcounts$symbol)
head(backgroundgenes)
backgroundgenes <- backgroundgenes[!is.na(backgroundgenes)]
```

I removed a bunch of 'na's from the column because i don't need them.

```
degenes <- read.csv("degenes.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(degenes)
degenes <- as.character(degenes[,12])
degenes <- degenes[!is.na(degenes)]
```

same thing here. symbol was column 12 in this df. So now i have two characters with the same type of data in each, one about 24000 long and the other about 350 long.

```
gene.vector <- as.integer(backgroundgenes%in%degenes)
names(gene.vector) <- backgroundgenes
head(gene.vector)
```

Now i can see my gene.vector and it has all of the gene names with a 0 or a 1 underneath. so far so good.

```
#write as a table
write.table(gene.vector, file="outedgeR05vectortest.txt", sep="\t", quote = F, col.names=F)
```

And this is where it goes wrong. My output table has a column of ascending numbers from 1 to 25000 instead of my gene names. The second column has the correct number of 0s and 1s. I have already gotten this to work to the point where i've completed my downstream analysis using columns from the two gene sets that have ensembl gene identifiers (in the form ENSMUSG00048979 for example). i don't understand why the exact same code using different inputs won't work. Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] pathview_1.16.1                        org.Hs.eg.db_3.4.1                     gage_2.26.1                           
 [4] KEGG.db_3.2.3                          TxDb.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10.ensGene_3.4.0 GenomicFeatures_1.28.4                
 [7] GenomicRanges_1.28.3                   GenomeInfoDb_1.12.2                    org.Mm.eg.db_3.4.1                    
[10] GO.db_3.4.1                            AnnotationDbi_1.38.1                   IRanges_2.10.2                        
[13] S4Vectors_0.14.3                       Biobase_2.36.2                         BiocGenerics_0.22.0                   
[16] goseq_1.28.0                           geneLenDataBase_1.12.0                 BiasedUrn_1.07                        
[19] edgeR_3.18.1                           limma_3.32.2                           BiocInstaller_1.26.1                  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] graph_1.54.0               DBI_0.7                    Rsamtools_1.28.0           zlibbioc_1.22.0           
 [5] bitops_1.0-6               SummarizedExperiment_1.6.3 bit_1.1-12                 lattice_0.20-35           
 [9] RSQLite_2.0                pkgconfig_2.0.1            KEGGgraph_1.38.0           DelayedArray_0.2.7        
[13] rtracklayer_1.36.4         blob_1.1.0                 compiler_3.4.1             GenomicAlignments_1.12.1  
[17] biomaRt_2.32.1             png_0.1-7                  Rcpp_0.12.11               GenomeInfoDbData_0.99.0   
[21] httr_1.2.1                 tools_3.4.1                RCurl_1.95-4.8             BiocParallel_1.10.1       
[25] memoise_1.1.0              nlme_3.1-131               R6_2.2.2                   XVector_0.16.0            
[29] digest_0.6.12              Matrix_1.2-10              bit64_0.9-7                grid_3.4.1                
[33] XML_3.98-1.9               rlang_0.1.1                Biostrings_2.44.1          mgcv_1.8-17               
[37] Rgraphviz_2.20.0           matrixStats_0.52.2         KEGGREST_1.16.0            locfit_1.5-9.1            
[41] tibble_1.3.3
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `head(gene.vector)` Perhaps convert it to a data.frame prior `write.table`

Comment: `head(gene.vector)
  Xkr4    Rp1  Sox17 Mrpl15 Lypla1  Tcea1 
     0      0      0      0      0      0 `. interestingly when i converted it to a dataframe i got `gene.vector
1           0
2           0
3           0
4           0
5           0
6           0` which is exactly my problem. the gene symbols are replaced by numbers from 1 up.

Comment: try `output <-  data.frame(id = names(gene.vector ), gene.vector = gene.vector)` and then saving `output` with `write.table`

Comment: that worked, thanks!